# Typescript compiler not working

Tags: typescript, tsc

I am using `tsc -w` to compile my project. I've been using it for quite a long time now but it recently stopped working after a small refactoring for (really) no reason. When I run the command, it shows me instead `tsc --help`. I didn't touch the `tsconfig.json` which is still :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}
```

Did it happenned to anyone before? How can I resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Does the `tsc` compiler give an error message?

Comment: No, no matter what I  do it only shows possible commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that you are using a deprecated flag.

It is worth reviewing the listed options to see if you are using one that isn't listed, for example if you have:

```
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
```

But the help shows:

```
...
--allowUnusedLabels                 Do not report errors on unused labels.
-d, --declaration                   Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file.
--experimentalDecorators            Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators.
--forceConsistentCasingInFileNames  Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file.
...
```

In this case, (because it is alphabetical) I can see `emitDecoratorMetadata` is not there and removing it should make things work.

Note: this solution should work for any case where a previously working `tsc` command stops working.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me but I tought it can help someone else. I actually resolved the problem by executing the command in the folder where `tsconfig.json` is, but I I would like to emphasize the fact that I didn't change anything and it worked perfectly fine before. I noticed there are a lot of "weird" bugs like this with the tsc

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
"target": "es5",
```

to

```
"target": "es6",
```

That works for me.